# ValueError at scope name in tensorflow estimator

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

In `tensorflow estimator` I am facing a problem when I tried to working with `japanese` text. I try to find out it by debugging. The responsible line of code is

```
net = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features, params['feature_columns'])
```

from this line it raise a error and that is

> ValueError: 'こんにちは' is not a valid scope name

I also go through depth of it and finally got the regex in `ops.py`that is

- _VALID_OP_NAME_REGEX = re.compile("^[A-Za-z0-9.][A-Za-z0-9_.\-/]*$")
- _VALID_SCOPE_NAME_REGEX = re.compile("^[A-Za-z0-9_.\-/]*$")

Any suggesstion to skip this or any valid suggestion for feeding any language charecter.

**Note:** It's working fine when I am using `English`.

Answer (score 1):

Both for _VALID_OP_NAME_REGEX and _VALID_SCOPE_NAME_REGEX patterns look for names containing only ascii characters *[A-Za-z]*, digits *[0-9]* and some others *[_.-/]* to match. Since the term is in Japanese and the term's characters are not in the types in the pattern; it is giving you an exception. Therefore, you need to give a proper scope name in your feature parameters somehow (may be trying mapping terms to ascii ones?)

Cheers